# What exactly is it with KeyedSubtree

Tags: flutter

Trying to understand KeyedSubtree.

Is it for moving StateFull Widget around in the Element tree incl. sub Statefull Widgets?

Swapping Widget in a list using keys for Statefull widgets, works fine

```
- StatefullWidget(key): 1
-- State: 1
```

Swapping with keys works fine.

```
- StatefullWidget(key): 2
-- State: 2
```

I thought maybe `KeyedSubtree` should help mowing child StatefullWidgets, but maybe not as swapping StatefullWidgets incl. childrens state also works fine using a key.

```
- StatelessWidget(key): 1
-- StatefullWidget: 2
--- State: 2
```

Swapping incl. children states

```
- StatelessWidget(key): 3
-- StatefullWidget: 4
--- State: 4
```

Can you explain KeyedSubtree?

Comment: *"Can you explain KeyedSubtree?"* - i think that [KeyedSubtree](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/7e9793dee1/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart#L7257) implementation will explain it better - check how `build` method is implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually got here because I was confused as to what it does. Turns out it was in the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/KeyedSubtree-class.html) after all.

> A widget that builds its child.
>
> Useful for attaching a key to an existing widget.

Particularly this part: **"Useful for attaching a key to an existing widget."**

So if you have a widget that doesn't accept a key as an argument and you need to assign it a key, you simply do:

```
KeyedSubtree(
    key: ValueKey("some value"),
    child: WidgetThatNeedsKey()
)
```

What makes the widget confusing is that it doesn't seem to do anything.